# ReactJS - cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS, but I just stumbled upon this error which I can't figure out.

I want to change the parent's `items` array state from its children component. I tried to pass the `addItem` function as a prop to the `children` component, where on enter, the children component calls this function and passes in the input value.

When I try to `console.log(this.state.items)` in the addItem method, I get this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Main `App.js`

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p>Todo List</p>
                <AddItemBox addNewItem={this.addItem}/>
                <ItemsList items={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    addItem(item) {
        var listItems = this.state.items;
        listItems.push(item);
        this.setState({items: listItems});
    }
}
```

Child component: `AddItemBox.js`

```
class AddItemBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: '' // input value
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='AddItemBox'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='add item' onChange={e => {
                this.onInputChange(e.target.value)
            }} onKeyPress={e => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    this.onInputEnter(e.target.value)
                }
            }}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onInputChange(item) {
        this.setState({item});
    }

    onInputEnter(item) {
        // Now add it to the 'items' array state
        this.props.addNewItem(item);
        this.setState({item: ''});
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this in constructor: `this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)`

Comment: @AndrewLi Oh wow, that worked! Could you describe a little more? Thank you!

Comment: the `bind` function changes the `this` reference to the class itself (or whatever's `this` it was at the time) so it can reference `state`. Without it, the `this` references whatever called the function.

Answer (score 1):

I can help @AndrewLi explain. Check out this [article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/). It explains mid-way about why you need to bind your functions in React. The quick explanation comes down to `scope`.

What is `this` inside your addItem function? It might not be what you expect it to be. So you have to bind the appropriate `this` to the function so you can use it in the way you intend, like calling `this.state.items`. If `this` isn't the `this` you expect, you will get undesirable results.

So you can do this:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: '' // input value
        };
        
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
    }
```

Or you can use es6 and do this:

```js
addItem = (item) => {
    var listItems = this.state.items;
    listItems.push(item);
    this.setState({items: listItems});
}
```

Both give you the same results

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function as callback instead of reference in "AddItemBox" component as

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p>Todo List</p>
                <AddItemBox addNewItem={(item) => this.addItem(item)}/>
                <ItemsList items={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    addItem(item) {
        var listItems = this.state.items;
        listItems.push(item);
        this.setState({items: listItems});
    }
}
```

Also you need to bind the function in your constructor.